# SQL Update FK in Table A after insert in Table B from select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select

I am using MS SQL Server 2008,
I need insert some rows into table B from select statement and after insert I need update FK in Table A with new inserted Id's:
My code:

```
insert into TableB 
output inserted.Id as insId
SELECT   
someA,
someB 
FROM TableC u 
INNER JOIN TableD pd
ON u.Id=pd.ID
```

Then I need **Update** TableA with inserted.Id
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you know which rows in TableA to update?

Comment: I need update TableA.FKId column, where TableA.Id = TableC.Id

Comment: But, you want to update with some column that was inserted into TableB.  How does TableB relate to the rows that you want to update in TableA?  This question is very confusing.

Comment: From TableB I need only id's of new records for upodating TableA FKId col. Ok I try to simplify : I got some select 
SELECT   
someA,
someB 
FROM TableC u 
INNER JOIN TableD pd
ON u.Id=pd.ID
where I need 2 columns to insert in TableB and when insertion completes I need connect this records with records from selection by FK in TableA

Comment: Are you only inserting 1 row into TableB?  Or you are inserting many records, and need all of the IDs back out.  If you get many rows, how will you join each row added to TableB to TableA?

Comment: I am inserting many records in TableB, and need all of the IDs back out, about joining TableB to TableA I am not sure how exactly do this, logically I need to paste this Id's to TableA 

where TableA.Id = 
SELECT   
u.Id
FROM TableC u 
INNER JOIN TableD pd
ON u.Id=pd.ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/133933/is-it-possible-to-make-an-update-query-right-after-insert-returned-new-ids/133935#133935)

> [OUTPUT Clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)
>
> ```
> DECLARE @MyTableVar table( NewScrapReasonID smallint,
>                            Name varchar(50),
>                            ModifiedDate datetime);
> INSERT Production.ScrapReason (Name, ModifiedDate)  
>     OUTPUT INSERTED.ScrapReasonID, INSERTED.Name, INSERTED.ModifiedDate
>         INTO @MyTableVar
> VALUES (N'Operator error', GETDATE());
> ```
>
> you can then use table for other inserts / updates